# How to map id and name to the given sequence in scala

Tags: scala

How to map id and name to the given sequence in scala ... 
If suppose I have Input Sequence like this

```
Seq((1, "teja"), (2, "mahesh"))
```

and I need to get Output like

```
Map[("id" ->1 ,"name"->"teja"),("id" ->2,"name"->"mahesh")]
```

How to do it?

Comment: The output you provided is not valid. A map has keys and values - the map you've shown us is actually a flat list of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
scala> Seq((1, "teja"), (2, "mahesh")) map { case (id,name) => ("id" -> id, "name" -> name)  }
res0: Seq[((String, Int), (String, String))] = List(((id,1),(name,teja)), ((id,2),(name,mahesh)))
```

to keep the `->` in the toString use a Map

```
scala> Seq((1, "teja"), (2, "mahesh")) map { case (id,name) => Map("id" -> id, "name" -> name)  }
res1: Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] = List(Map(id -> 1, name -> teja), Map(id -> 2, name -> mahesh))
```

if you need it within a map you can do

```
scala> Seq((1, "teja"), (2, "mahesh")).map { case (id,name) => ("id" -> id, "name" -> name)  }.toMap
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, Int),(String, String)] = Map((id,1) -> (name,teja), (id,2) -> (name,mahesh))
```

then the key will be a Tuple2[String,Int] though.